# Python Recursive Function. TypeError: table() missing 1 required positional argument: 'm'

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm a total beginner in programming and I am trying to print a table of 5 with a recursive function. I have been getting this error which I don't understand. Can anyone help me with this?

Code:

```
def table(n,m):
  i = 0
  while i < 11:
    if n>0:
      result = n * table(m+1)
      print(result)
    else:
      result = 1
    return result
    i += 1
  
table(5,3)
```

Error:
TypeError: table() missing 1 required positional argument: 'm'

Comment: As the error says, `table` takes two arguments, but you're calling it with one when you write `table(m+1)`. What are you expecting the value of `m` to be when you write `table(m+1)`?

Comment: Got it, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Error is in this statement. `result = n * table(m+1)`
- Your function `table(n,m)` accepts two arguments. But you are only giving one argument `table(m+1)`.

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In line 5 of your code, you call the `table()` function and the function takes 2 arguements but you provided only 1 i.e., `m + 1` which is considered one value not two because m when added with 1 will become one value. Hence, the error.

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot!